# My correlation ids aren't showing in the ULS logs, what may be causing this?

Tags: logging, uls

I've added all of my SharePoint service accounts to the Domain Admins group which are in the local administrators but I'm still getting ids that don't exist in the logs.  I am running a single server farm in a VM so the files shouldn't be on some other server.

I also tried using the Powershell command to retrieve the error details and that also was unsuccessful.

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you have changed the Logging settings by category to omit certain categories?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? If yes, could you post the answer?